# Quand et pourquoi "losange" a remplace "rhombe" ?

Tags: étymologie, histoire, mathématiques, latin, grec

Quand et pourquoi le mot *losange* a-t-il communément remplacé *rhombe* ?
Littré, n'en parle pas ; ni TLFi: *[losange](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/losange)*; *[rhombe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rhombe)*

Peut-on utiliser rhombe ? Serait-on compris ?
Y a-t-il d'autres cas ou des termes mathématiques venant du latin ou du grec ancien qui ont été similairement remplacés ?

**EDIT**

> D'après wikipédia : Il (le losange) était anciennement appelé rhombe
>   du grec ρόμβος (et porte toujours un nom tiré de cette étymologie dans
>   de **nombreuses langues**, comme rhombus en anglais ou encore rombo en
>   espagnol et en italien). L'adjectif qui lui est relatif est rhombique.

De plus, romb en roumain, Rhombus en allemand.
Je me demande pourquoi les autres langues et plus particulièrement les langues romanes) ont retenu les mots venant du grec et pas le français.

Comment: Bonne question, j'ai appris un mot, et je suis certain de ne jamais l'avoir lu ou entendu de ma vie.

Comment: @Jardindefrostedflakes Merci pour le commentaire. Tu parles de quel mot ? losange ou rhombe ?

Comment: Sûrement de *rhombe*, c'est pareil pour moi.

Comment: Ah si, ça me revient, j'ai visité la pyramide rhomboïdale.

Comment: @jlliagre: Donc, si je comprends ça fait bien de temps que l'on emploie losange et pas rhombe, non ?

Comment: On a toujours employé *losange* qui est probablement plus ancien que *rhombe*. *Rhombe* a subsisté en tant que terme savant jusqu'à la moitié du XIXe siècle après quoi il n'a quasiment plus été utilisé pour désigner un losange.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça c'est la réponse que j'ai (re)cherchée:-)!

Comment: Un rhomboèdre est un solide avec 6 faces en losange (dont le cube est un cas particulier). Le terme est utilisé notamment en cristallographie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

◊

> Quand et pourquoi le mot losange a-t-il communément remplacé rhombe ?

*Losange* n'a pas remplacé *rhombe*, car il est probablement tout aussi ancien, voire plus. Les deux mots étaient concurrents mais *rhombe* n'a pas survécu.

Alors que celle de *rhombe* ne fait pas de doute, l'étymologie de *losange* n'est pas clairement établie.

On suggère que ce serait un doublon avec louange(s) (du latin *laudare*), louanges  représentées par des dessins inscrits dans des losanges dans l'héraldique médiévale, on dit aussi qu'il seraient nommés ainsi à cause de leur forme rappelant celle des feuilles de laurier (latin *laurus*), il existerait un hypothétique *loxangle* du grec λοξός et du latin *angulus*, (angle de biais), on parle enfin de la forme d'une pierre plate ([lauze](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lauze)) ou de celle d'un gateau aux amandes arabe (*lawzinaj*) qui aurait selon certains aussi donné *lasagne*...

> Peut-on utiliser rhombe ?

Pourquoi pas, tout dépend de son objectif.

> Serait-on compris ?

Non, ou au mieux par une infime minorité de son auditoire ou de ses lecteurs.

> Y a-t-il d'autres cas ou des termes mathématiques venant du latin ou du grec ancien qui ont été similairement remplacés ?

Je n'en vois pas. En élargissant un peu la recherche, on trouve peut-être *[polymathique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/polymathique)*  et *[disquisition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/disquisition)*, aujourd'hui supplantés par *encyclopédique* et *investigation*.

◊

Comment: Merci bien ! C'est une réponse encyclopédique :-)!

Answer (score 1):

Les *rhombes* existent toujours, ils se présentent le plus souvent sous le nom de [Dodécaèdre rhombique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dod%C3%A9ca%C3%A8dre_rhombique)

> Comme de nombreux polyèdres convexes, le *dodécaèdre rhombique* peut
>   être étoilé en étendant ses arêtes ou faces planes jusqu'à ce que
>   chacune d'entre elles se rejoignent de nouveau.
>
> La première étoile, aussi appelée polyèdre d'Escher peut être vue
>   comme un *dodécaèdre rhombique* avec des pyramides à base rhombique (en
>   forme de **losange**) collées sur ses faces, ou encore comme trois
>   octaèdres imbriqués.

Le losange est donc né du dodécaèdre rhombique comme le montre l'image ci-dessous:
[image: L'hexagramme, {6/2}, la stellation d'un hexagone et un composé de deux triangles.]
[image]

[Source image](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellation)